# Python DataFrame: inverse distance probability for each row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas DataFrame` for example of shape (2697, 30) where each cell is a normalized distance (each row sums up to one). I now want to convert each row to probabilities where the lowest distance should get the highest probability. I know the formula which is

```
1/d  / sum(1/d)
```

Yet I have no idea on how to implement this. A `DataFrame.apply` can (I think) not execute this (correct me if I'm wrong please, I really like to learn).

EDIT:
I also have the original unnormalized distances if that may help

Comment: Updated my answer, pls check. This should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

df = df.apply(lambda x: 1 / x)
x = df.values #returns a numpy array
scaler = preprocessing.Normalizer(norm='l1')
x_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x)
df = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled, columns=df.columns)
```